# How to strip beginning and end of a line in a file

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file with a list of links, but they have unusable leads and trails I need to get rid of.

Specifically `<img src="place-holder" />`.

The file is full of 20-odd similar links with all that garbage, I just need `place-holder`.

If this was a single link that'd be easy;

```
link='${link#*"}' && link='${%"*}' && echo $link
```

There's probably a way to do this in a single command but I don't know how, also I don't deal with lists in files

So question is; How do I get rid of anything outside and including the quotes in a list within a file to then iterate over?

So far I haven't got a clue even though I've been searching for a few hours now.
Since these are all equal length I *think* a sed operation getting rid of things in a set position might be possible

Comment: While I have you here, you guys in Lambda have got to stop messing around with those portals! Who knows what could happen!

Answer (score 1):

### Complex data

This makes some assumptions that:

- tags/attributes are lower case
- there is only one img tag per line
- the whole img tag is on one line

```
echo 'asdfasf <img src="placeholder" asfd="asdfasdf" /> frog' \
     | sed -E 's/.*< *img[^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^>]*\/>.*/\1/g'
```

result:

```
placeholder
```

Regex breakdown:

- `.*` stuff before tag
- `< *img` tag opening, optional spaces
- `[^>]*` as many non-`>` characters as possible
- `src=` src attribute
- `"([^"]*)"` capture everything inside the quotes
- `[^>]*\/>` the rest of the tag
- `.*` stuff after the tag

### Simple data

If your data is as simple as `<img src="place-holder" />`, perhaps the folowing will work for you

```
echo '<img src="place-holder" />' | sed -E 's/.*"(.*)".*/\1/g'
```

output:

```
placeholder
```

### I hate `sed`

If you must:

```
echo '<img src="place-holder" />' | cut -d'"' -f2
```

### I could go all day

Why not:

```
 echo '<img src="place-holder" />' | awk -v FS='"' '{ print $2 }'
```

### AutoHotkey?

I mean, I suppose...

```
for tag in '<img src="place-holder" />' '<img src="place2" />'; do echo $tag; done | \
    sed -E 's/"/\\"\\"/g' | xargs -I {} echo -e \
    "Result := RegExReplace(\"{}\`n\",\"^.*\"\"(.*)\"\".*$\",\"\$1\`n\")\n" \
    "FileAppend %Result%, *" | pwsh.exe -c "AutoHotkey.exe * | echo"
```

I... I can't believe I actually got that last one to work...

Comment: god I hate sed, whelp time to learn how to use it!

Comment: why even bother with advanced sed now? I just gotta push #line to STDIN capture everything inside qutes and append to a new file, then replace od with new.

Thanks lad/lass!

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, but I guess I was assuming there could be other stuff including quotes, img attributes, etc, on the same line. Yeah, of course simpler is better.

Comment: this is wht the data looks like;

```<img src="place-holder" />

<img src="place-holder" />

<img src="place-holder" />
<img src="place-holder" />```

Comment: Ok, added a simpler regex for only that case. Hell, if it's really that simple, you could probably use `cut`.

Comment: No need to push the line to `stdin`, the `-i` option allows `sed` to edit the file in-place...